# RabbitMQ conncetion refused

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am not able to conncet to RabbitMQ.RabbitMQ is not on local machine .

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.EnableRabbit;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;

@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class AMQPConfig {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitMQProperties rabbitMQProperties;

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(rabbitMQProperties.getQueueName(), false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(rabbitMQProperties.getExchangeName());
    }



    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(rabbitMQProperties.getRoutingKey());
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                             MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        System.out.println( " ques name is ------- "  + rabbitMQProperties.getQueueName() );
        container.setQueueNames(rabbitMQProperties.getQueueName());
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate amqpTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(RabbitMqListener listener) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "listen");
    }

}
```

My application.properties looks like

```
spring.rabbitmq.password=pass
spring.rabbitmq.port=15671
spring.rabbitmq.username=user
spring.rabbitmq.host=https://urltologinscreen
```

I am able to access to Rabbitmq gui using 
https://urltologinscreen:15671

I am getting the below error

> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
>        : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
>        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 
>        'container' defined in class path resource [pathhidden/rabbitmq/AMQPConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through
>        method 'container' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
>        No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory' 
>         available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
>
> ```
>   Parameter 0 of method amqpTemplate in pathhidden.rabbitmq.AMQPConfig required a bean of type
> ```
>
> 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory' that
>   could not be found.

How do i resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution that worked for me

1. Make sure RabbitMQ is defined on your properties file

```
    spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
    spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
    spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
    spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

2. On your pom.xml file, ensure to add the tag below under dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you properties should be like so:

```
spring.rabbitmq.password=pass
spring.rabbitmq.username=user
spring.rabbitmq.host=urltologinscreen
```

Don't need to specify the port or use `http` in the host

Comment: rabbitmq is installed on another machine.Do i need to add anything more?